# Spectral norm of a random matrix whose entries are product of two standard gaussians

Tags: statistics, inequality, random-variables, random-matrices, spectral-norm

While solving a research problem related to approximations in neural networks, I've faced the following problem which I have not been able to solve after trying different approaches for a while.

Let's say that we have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n x n}$ whose entries are each random varianbles $a_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m x_{ik} x_{jk}$ where $x_{ab} \sim N(0, 1)$ and each of the random variables $x_{ab}$ are independent of the other ones (unless both indices of $x$ are the same, in which case it will be the same random variable).

The question is: can we bound the spectral norm of the matrix $A$?
A simpler version of the question which has the same value for me, is if we can bound the spectral value of matrix $A$ while zero-ing out its diagonal values. I can see that the latter version might be simpler, as in the diagonal, the random variables $x_{ii}$ are not independent. But I'd definitely be happier to know about the general solution to this problem.

P.S.: I know that we can bound this value by $\infty$, but I would love to know if there is any tight bound already available on this. In particular, I would like to know about bounds that are dependent on the variable $m$, but any insight could be helpful for me and is much appreciated.

I know that the product of two independent standard normal random variables is a form of K-Distributions, as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian), but as this distribution is not a [sub-gaussian distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804093/product-of-sub-gaussian-rvs/2736622#:%7E:text=The%20product%20of%20two%20sub,gaussian%20as%20not%20sub%2Dgaussian.&text=Both%20(X%2BY)2,variables%20is%20also%20sub%2Dexponential.) I couldn't use the available resources that discuss spectral norm of random matrices whose entries are sub-gaussian.
The other path that I've tried is bounding spectral norm by frobenius norm, but as the K-distribution is distributed around zero (and has mean zero), $x_{ab}^2$ does not have zero mean, and things got a bit messy as I couldn't come up with a concentration inequality to continue this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are the $x_{a,b}$ **jointly** independent?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $x_{a,b}$. In the question, $x_{ab}$ is one random variable identified by two indices. Could you please clarify?

Comment: It seems your matrix is a product of two (non-symmetric) Gaussian matrices. I would think a lot is known.

Comment: I actually couldn't write it as a product of two Gaussian matrices, because of the sum that is there. Do you have any idea on how it can be written as that kind of product? @lcv

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it seems that $A = XX^T$ with $X_{ij}=x_{ij}$. That should get you started